# using inheritance or adding a column for type in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm using PostgreSQL. I have a `category_master` table that other category tables (such as `customer_cat`, `product_cat`, ...) inherit from (because I am going to select all categories with one query).

I have 3 options to run this, I am wondering which one is the best?

1. Creating one table named `catgory_relation` which has a column named `type`.

   The `catgory_relation` table includes these columns: `id`, `object_id`, `object_type`.
2. Creating one table named `catgory_relation_master` that other `catgory_relation` tables inherit from, and `catgory_relation_master` includes these columns: `id`, `object_id`.

   Moreover, I have some tables such as `category_relation_customer`, `category_relation_product` etc. that inherit from `catgory_relation_master` table as well.
3. Creating relation tables for every category relation, without creating a master table.

Furthermore,  I want to know that if creating a column as "type" can save the server space compared to creating tables for every category relation?

Comment: Are these really different types of categories? Or is it just what can reference them? How big do you expect this table to get?

Comment: Yes, they are different. Customers category, products category etc.
The `category_master ` will be contained less than 1000 rows, and `category_relation_master`  about 8000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If these are really categories, I'd model them differently.

For each category, have a small table that contains the possible value (a lookup table):

```
CREATE TABLE color (
   color_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   color_name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Then add a foreign key column referencing `color` to the table that you want to categorize.

With that, I would prefer a category table per category, because otherwise the `type` would have to be part of the foreign key, if you want to make clear what type a certain row belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I  am going to select all categories with one query. Also, I need search in all category by name. If I do based on your advice, it seems that I should join all tables.